# send dhtmlcgrid cell data to dhtmlxwindow

Tags: php, dhtmlx

I am currently using dhtmlxgrid to display mysql records to the user. When the user selects a specific cell (in column 9), a new dhtmlxwindow pops up displaying a form and more data from a mysql table. I need to get the value of the grid row's first column cell and send that data to the dhtmlxwindow to use in my MySQL query.

NOTE: I am using attachURL(); to display an html page within my pop-up window so I need the grid data to be sent to the new window and then to the url page included in the window.

How do I get the grid data sent to the ultimate destination?

All help is appreciated.

My CODE:

Grid/Window Init:

```
 <div id="gridbox" style="padding-right: 5%; padding-left: 5.5%; padding-bottom: 2%; border: none; width: 78%; height: 680px;"></div>

 <br/>
 <br/>


<script>

mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');

//the path to images required by grid 
    mygrid.setImagePath("./codebase/imgs/");                 
    mygrid.setHeader("WO,C.R. Start,Prod Stage,Customer,Part Number,FT<sup>2</sup>,Total Units,CR1,CR2,Floor Notes,Production Notes");
    mygrid.attachHeader("#text_filter, ,#text_filter,#text_filter, , , ,#text_filter,#text_filter, , ,");
    mygrid.setInitWidthsP("5,8,8,9,10,4,4,6,6,6,*");          
            mygrid.setColAlign("center,center,left,left,center,center,center,center,center,center,left");       //the alignment of columns   
    mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro");                 
    mygrid.setColSorting("str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str");           
    mygrid.setColumnIds("workorder,cleanroom_start,productionstage,customer,partnumber,totalsqft,quantity,claveid,claveid2,floornotes,productionnotes")

    var combobox = mygrid.getCombo(2);
    combobox.put("Cleanroom Done","Cleanroom Done")

    mygrid.attachEvent("onCellMarked",doOnCellSelected);
    mygrid.enableMarkedCells(true);
    mygrid.enableBlockSelection(true);
    mygrid.enableRowsHover(true,'grid_hover');

    mygrid.init();    


//==========================================================================
mygrid.load("gridview_Testing_GET.php");
myDataProcessor = new dataProcessor("gridview_Testing_UPDATE.php");
myDataProcessor.enableDataNames(true);
myDataProcessor.setUpdateMode("cell");
myDataProcessor.setTransactionMode("GET");
myDataProcessor.init(mygrid);
//==============================================================================

function doOnCellSelected(rid,ind) {

        if (ind == 9) {

            var sgref = mygrid.cells(rid,0).getValue();

            var dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
            wFloornotes = dhxWins.createWindow("wFloornotes", 100, 100, 450, 400);
            wFloornotes.setText("Floornotes");
            wFloornotes.center();


            wFloornotes.attachURL('floornotes_datalist.php');

        }
}

</script>
```

I need the grid cell value to be accessible from floornotes_datalist.php.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to use:
wFloornotes.attachURL('floornotes_datalist.php?sgref='+sgref);

Comment: Thank you for responding to this. I had initially tried that method during testing, but to no avail. However, I was finally able to send my variable to my floornotes page via: wFloornotes.attachURL('floornotes_datalist.php', null, {sgref, sgref}); I used $sgref = $_POST['sgref']; to grab the value.